# Select item in Angular drop down

Tags: angularjs

I have a web app written using mvc and angular.  I have an issue where when loading a record, the select does not select any value.  My textboxes and checkboxes all work, but my selects don't.  My html for my select is

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-4">
          Project Type
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-4">
           <select ng-options="ProductType.Value for ProductType in ProductTypes track by ProductType.Id"
               class="form-control" ng-model="Dissemination.ProductType"></select>        
     </div>
</div>
```

The dropdown is loaded on page load.

```
angular.module('DisseminationApp').controller('DisseminationProjectInfoController', function ($scope, $http, validationMethods, dataService, ProjectServiceFactory) {
    $scope.ShowProject = false;
    $scope.ProductTypes = dataService.getProductTypes();
});
```

The service is just returning hard coded values for the select.

```
function getProductTypes() {
        var values = [];
        values.push({ Id: '52146595-0DC6-4A81-9C18-0482C817F724', Value: 'Option 1'});
        values.push({ Id: 'F61D261E-895E-4039-A125-C29972673623', Value: 'Option 2'});
        return values;
    };
```

I then have a click event that is the item.

```
 <div class="row" ng-repeat="dissemination in Disseminations|orderBy:sort.column:sort.descending">
            <div class="col-md-2" ng-click="OpenRecord(dissemination)">
                link
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{dissemination.TypeString}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{dissemination.Title}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                {{dissemination.CreateDateString}}
            </div>
        </div>
```

And in this click event, I open up the dialog and set the scope value to the new dissemination.  Everything works except for the dropdown values.

```
$scope.OpenRecord = function (newValue) {
        if (newValue != undefined) {
            $("#DisseminationId").modal('show');
            alert(newValue.ProductType.toUpperCase() == '52146595-0DC6-4A81-9C18-0482C817F724');
            $scope.Dissemination = newValue;
            $scope.Dissemination.ProductType = $scope.Dissemination.ProductType.toUpperCase();
            alert($scope.Dissemination.ProductType);
        }
    });
```

The first alert comes back as true and the second alert is set to the correct value.  Example of issue is here https://plnkr.co/edit/vDC0uu6MD3h6r3Woruo9?p=streamer

Comment: I'm reading your question again, and I'm wondering if I am understanding the problem correctly.  It seems like maybe you are having an issue because your `ProductType` for the dropdown is an object, with (for example) `'52146595-0DC6-4A81-9C18-0482C817F724'` in the `Id` property, while in the `Dissemination` object, `ProductType` is a string.

Comment: does the following `ng-options` clause work?:  `ng-options="ProductType.Value for ProductType.Id in ProductTypes track by ProductType.Id"`

Comment: ok I got the syntax right now after playing in plunker for a sec:  https://plnkr.co/edit/xylRlhf1ts6rgiclDPsJ.  `ng-options="ProductType.Id as ProductType.Value for ProductType in ProductTypes track by ProductType.Id`.  You might not even need the `track by` clause in this instance.

Comment: it's hard to identify the relationship between your dropdown and the rest of the HTML from the snippets you've posted;  is there any way you can create a [mcve] showing their exact layout?

Comment: The Minimal, complete and verifiable example has been posted to the question.

Comment: As I suspected, the `track by` clause changes the output of the `ng-model` enough that it doesn't match.  without the `track by`, this works.  I modified the example slightly, to show it switches correctly.  https://plnkr.co/edit/jlRCXVV7cxq6lbRBTv7x?p=preview